# Configuration of CNAME and MX records

Tags: hosting, cname, cloud-hosting, mx-record

I have a domain(www.mydomain.com) hosted with 1 service provider along with emails. My application is on my cloud providers network(app.mycloudprovider.com). So i have following entries in my CName and MX-

```
CNAME(Name -> Value) -
www.mydomain.com -> app.mycloudprovider.com
webmail -> mail.domain-hosting-provider.com

MX (Name -> Value)
mydomain.com -> mail.domain-hosting-provider.com
```

Lately i noticed that if i type www.mydomain.com i got my site if not if i type mydomain.com. So i added 1 CName as -

```
mydomain.com -> app.mycloudprovider.com
```

Now i am not able to get any emails on my email id - support@mydomain.com, which i think because of adding new cname entry. Can someone please tell me how this can be configured? I do not have any A name or AAAA name.

Answer (score 0):

You broke it! You cannot have CNAME records at the root of the domain, because the CNAME aliases all types of data, i.e. it aliases your MX records, as well as SOA, NS, etc. that technically must exist at the root of the domain.

So for pointing `mydomain.com` as entered into the browser to a physical server, you must use an A record.